# How to get feature id in visual studio for feature stapling in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm about to try feature stapling for the first time and I read for example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544294.aspx
and
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/b75a103c-0a6a-47c2-b80b-df821718b897/

What I don't get is how I get the feature GUID or do I make one up myself?

```
<FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="[FEATURE GUID]"
TemplateName="BLOG#0" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: nevermind, I right-clicked on the feature but saw no GUID in the properties. Double-clicked on the feature instead and got saw all properties by selecting the feature in the packaging explorer

Answer (score 0):

there are several tokens available within SharePoint 2010 projects, which will be translated from MSBuild.

You can find more information on that topic on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231545(VS.100).aspx

Perhaps you have to add your file extensions as supported filetype for these tokens... Depends on your filetype..

Answer (score 0):

[john](https://stackoverflow.com/users/956275/john):
 I right-clicked on the feature but saw no GUID in the properties. Double-clicked on the feature instead and got saw all properties by selecting the feature in the packaging explorer